# Remove top menu from product and product display page?

Tags: magento-1.7, menu, local.xml

I am trying to remove top menu from product and product display page. I created local.xml file and added below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version = "0.1.0">
    <default>
        <catalog_category_default>
           <reference name="header">
              <remove name="top.menu" />
           </reference>
        </catalog_category_default>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But this is not working. How to remove? what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mentioning category pages and product view pages, then try this in your `local.xml` file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <layout version = "0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view>
        <remove name="top.menu" />
    </catalog_category_view>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="top.menu" />
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**Note** : You should make sure that, `local.xml` file resides in the correct package/theme location

Comment: @PrashantTapase the code that you have shown above will not work in theory. Because it holds `layout` node inside `default` node.

Comment: ...and my code will work...100% sure. I tried it in my local instance.

Comment: @PrashantTapase you should try my code exactly as that. ie you dont need `<?xml version="1.0" ?> <layout version = "0.1.0"> <default>` to use this part

Comment: yup. glad to help you.

Comment: But as per my knowledge we need keep fix code `<?xml version="1.0" ?> <layout version = "0.1.0"> <default> ......</default> </layout>` and inbetween that we write code...

Comment: @PrashantTapase nope. you can use this in every xml file `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`. You can also specify the version on `layout` node (not necessary). But you should not enclose everything inside `default` handle. You are wrong on that. so if you want to follow best practices. this is how your layout xml file look like `<?xml version="1.0" ?><layout version = "0.1.0"></layout>`. But without specify them, your code should work. ie `<layout></layout>`. The big rule here is, your updates should be enclosed in `layout` node

Comment: @PrashantTapase see the updated code. that is the best practice. But simply using `<layout>` will work. I normally use it for development purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version = "0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name = "left">
            <action method = "unsetChild"><name>topMenu</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name = "header">
            <action method = "insert"><blockName>top.menu</blockName></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

just change the reference name. that is unset the "left" and insert in "header".Hope it helps you.

Comment: your logic is correct but it is not working for me. i think my local.xml is not working.

Comment: this should work have you cleared magento cache

Comment: @donika : Not working . I cleared my cache

Comment: this will not work, as far as I know